# What does $\varepsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ literately mean?

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, descriptive-statistics

I see the notation such that $\varepsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ many times. And $
\varepsilon$ means error. Somehow, I can't really get the picture of it. What does this really mean?

Comment: "$\epsilon$ is distributed as a normal random variable with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$."

Comment: That is what I am asking. What does "$\varepsilon$ is normally distributed" mean?

Comment: Are you familiar with what a normal distribution is?

Comment: I know what it is. The problem is to understand the meaning of error is normally distributed.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the errors are normally distributed with 0 mean and a variance of $\sigma^2$

We normally assume these errors are independent too (but not always).

This means that we generally model our variables $y_i$ as:

$y_i = \hat{y}_i + \epsilon_i$

Where $\hat{y}_i$ is a known prediction of our outcome $y_i$ (depending on some explanatory variables), and the zero-mean random variable $\epsilon_i$ gives us a small random deviation from this prediction.